# Bind event using off and on methods in JQuery

Tags: jquery, performance, event-handling

I'm a newbie in JQuery , I've always wondering why some developers frequently use this syntax:
 `$("#someElem").off("change").on("change", function () { //TODO: })`,
 to bind some event ? 
Is it any advantages to using it this way, instead of just to use 
                                                                      `$("#someElem").on("change", function () { //TODO: })` , 
is it best practice to add **off()** method before, and what reason for doing it this way ?

Comment: That's what some "developers" do when they have no idea what they are doing, and can't even keep track of the event handlers they bind to each element, so they have to use `off` to make sure it's not bound more than once. It's not a "best practice", more a hack when you've lost control over the code you're writing.

Comment: To add to what @adeneo said, a better pattern is to use delegated events instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it any advantages to using it this way

What they're trying to do is *remove* any potential handlers, that were already attached to the Element.

So, it is to make sure that the only handler that will be called is the one which is currently provided.

If `off` is not called, the current handler will be called *along with* some previously attached handlers. It doesn't overwrite, instead executes all the handlers that are set.

If you know what you're doing, then you do not need to call `off`, but it isn't called "best practice", but more of a hack as @adeneo said.